# Power Meter - Modbus RS485 - After 5 to 6 hours, the device doesn't answer anymore

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, pymodbus, minimalmodbus

Using a Raspberry PI, I've written a loop in Python reading 6 registers of a Polier MTR5LMOD, every 15 sec, using the waveshare 2-ch rs485 hat.

The program works during 5 to 6 hours (sometime less, sometime more)... and suddenly... the device doesn't answer any more (no response) !

I reboot the system / I reboot the Polier... but nothing changes.

To test further I used [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) to successfully check comms. I launch my program, it works for 5 to 6 hours. Then the device doesn't answer. I reuse modpoll and the device doesn't answer. After leaving everything overnight both modpoll and my program both work again.

I tried different libraries : UMODBUS or MinimalModBus Or PyModBus.

I've checked several time my wiring and hardware : the cable is less than 10m, with resistance in both sides of 120 Ohms.

The device restart sometimes, like the day after, but no action was taken...

Has anybody faced such situation and found its root cause?

Comment: "I reboot the system / I reboot the Polier... but nothing changes" - so what does get things working again?

Comment: No clue... Just I restart the program after a good night sleep... :)

Comment: So restarting the application does temporarily fix the issue but it reoccurs later? (this is important because it points towards an issue with your application rather than an issue with the device). If you want to test this try leaving a known good application (e.g.  [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) or [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) running and see if that stops after a day or so.

Comment: Here is the scenario: I use modpoll, the device answers pretty well. I launch my program, it works for 5 to 6 hours. Then the device doesn't answer. I reuse modpoll and the device doesn't answer... I wait for the night, and modpoll or my program work again !!!

Comment: Seems unusual that such an issue would not be resolved by rebooting both devices (I assume you cut the power?). My guess would be a hardware issue; perhaps try polling the power meter from different machine in an attempt to isolate the problem component (have had issues with Modbus devices locking and being reset by a watchdog but this generally happens fairly quickly).

Comment: Have you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons,

1. Polling too fast leads to flow control or overflow on device
2. Device goes to sleep mode
3. The baud rate changed due to crystal/quartz phase shifting

You could try serial port monitoring tools to debug the underlying communication, check what happens exactly during the abnormal period.